# Xamarin Grid of Buttons or DataGrid for Generating a Playing Field for Numbers Based Game

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, datagrid, sudoku

I'm building a numbers based game similar to sudoku on Xamarin. I'm targetting both Android and iPhone, however, focusing on Android first. I've seen the SF Datagrid, and I've also seen the licensing price for that, but I've also seen some Unity tutorials that simply have a two-dimensional array of buttons. For Xamarin, targetting both iOS and Android, would a field of buttons plus an additional 10 buttons on the bottom for the input of the digits 0-9 be ok, or would a data table of some sort be more efficient and easier to code? I don't know if the table will be a 4x4, 6x6, 8x8, 10x10, 12x12, 14x14, or 16x16 until the game or "puzzle" is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, there will be some options to select the level of the game, then based on the selected grade,we can determine whether the table is 4x4, 6x6, 8x8, 10x10, 12x12, 14x14, or 16x16.

For the table,we have many methods to achieve this, a simple method is to use `Grid` .
And there is a sample ,you can check it out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/bugsweeper/). It might help you.